# How to express infinity in Prolog?

Tags: random, prolog, infinity

I am trying to use random/3

```
random(+L:int, +U:int, -R:int)
```

Is there any thing that can be used for representing infinity?

**For Example:**

```
random(0, Infinity, Random_Number).
```

Is it possible to achieve this with random? Or is there any other simple alternative?

**P.S.** I have made clpfd programs where I have used sup ( Supremum ), but I am not working with clpfd.

Comment: "Infinity" would make no sense for `random/3` ... how would generate a uniformly random number between 0 and infinity? On the other hand, for [`between/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3), it _does_ make sense ... it's `inf` (but that's just predicate-specific)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer so what do you suggest?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer how do I say that select a random number from zero to infinity?

Comment: You can't select such a number (that's like choosing a "real" (N.B. _not_  a `float`) between 0 and 1.0). You can only select up to some maximum.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer So I will have to give a limit?

Comment: Yes... Imagine the computer chooses randomly a 10000 trillion digits long number. Do you want to be given that?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Alright! thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: The analogue is [`random/1`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=random/1) where you get a random float between 0.0 and 1.0 (probably generated by randomly setting the bits of the mantissa and exponent)

Comment: `random_real_0_1([X|XS]):- freeze(XS, (random(0,2,X), random_real_0_1(XS))).` could be said to _be_ that real number, couldn't it? I then could `random_real_0_1_to_prec(N,Y):- random_real_0_1(X), length(Y,N),append(Y,[_|_],X).` @DavidTonhofer

Comment: @WillNess Well, actually it is a stream of bits, out of which you then sample `N` bits. The probability of getting any of the possible bitstring of N bits of fair coin tosses is well defined (2^-N), But "selecting a random number between 0 and infinity" is not that - it is selecting any infinite number of bits from that stream. Not only is doing so prohibited in this universe, the probability of getting any precise number is 0. Maybe you could get very lucky and hit a number which has only 0s after finite position K. :-) See also: [Book of Sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Sand)

Comment: You cannot get a random number uniformly b/w `0` and `inf`, but if you just do not want to give an upper limit, you can just pipe a random interval through a function that spans infinite on the interval. It will *_not_* be uniformly distributed. A not so good example is `1/x`,  if you do `random(X), Y is floor(1/X).` most of the numbers will be near 1 but without an upper limit as such.

Comment: @rajashekar That must be the "black swan distribution" ...

Comment: @DavidTonhofer the number pi is in universal agreement to be indeed existing, despite having infinite number of digits (right?). saying "a number with all digits 0, past e.g. 10th" is just as algorithmic a description as the one I gave, or as a short formula capable of generating the sequence of digits of pi to any given precision. but no real is ever sampled to the infinite precision, always to some finite one. as long as there's no limit on that choice, we consider it well defined. a precise distance is [an abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).

Comment: (by "pi formula" I meant something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm)

Comment: @WillNess Finitists may disagree concerning the existenc of Pi, but yes ... as long as the a Turning Machine to generate the digits can be written down, I'm good with that (but reals, transcendental or otherwise that can be written down by TMs are of course, tenuously rare). But if you cut off the digit stream at some N, you are not sampling from reals between 0 and infinity, you are sampling integers from 0 to 2^N-1. (I mean, evidently, right?)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer see my answer for a Turing machine (expressed using Prolog syntax) that doesn't cut off the digit stream at any fixed N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an amusing discussion in the comments. My underdeveloped intuition for infinite numbers and math tells me:

There is a finite number of integers that can be represented on a physical computer using a consistent representation. So there will be an infinity of other integers that cannot be represented. So, if you randomly pick *any* number, the probability that you can represent it on your machine is 0. You might as well define:

```
random_between(0, infinite, infinite).
```

[Transfinite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_number) *might be* one place to start reading, but who am I to say. You need a *mathematician* for that kind of questions, not a programming pedestrian.

Maybe you should ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/?

---

To your question: you can represent the concept of infinity with a symbol, for example the atom `infinite`. Then you need to decide how you treat that concept in your algebra, and provide rules for it. The `random_between/3` above is just one example. For inspiration, check out [how floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) handle infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the discussion in the comments has taken a less than useful turn. David is right that there is no way to get a *uniform* integer without an upper bound, but it's not clear if that's what you want. There are absolutely ways of getting unbounded random integers from a *skewed* distribution, where numbers closer to 0 will be more likely than numbers further away from 0, but *no* integer, not even one with 10000 trillion digits, is impossible. (As long as you don't exceed Prolog's memory.)

Here's a simple generator. First, lists of random length:

```
random_length(List) :-
    random(P),
    (   P > 0.25
    ->  List = [_ | Tail],
        random_length(Tail)
    ;   List = [] ).
```

Examples:

```
?- random_length(List).
List = [].

?- random_length(List).
List = [_2004, _2022, _2040, _2058, _2076].

?- random_length(List).
List = [].

?- random_length(List).
List = [_2004, _2022, _2040, _2058].
```

Next, random-length lists of random bits:

```
random_bit(Bit) :-
    random(P),
    (   P > 0.5
    ->  Bit = 1
    ;   Bit = 0 ).

random_bits(Bits) :-
    random_length(Bits),
    maplist(random_bit, Bits).
```

Examples:

```
?- random_bits(Bits).
Bits = [0].

?- random_bits(Bits).
Bits = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0].

?- random_bits(Bits).
Bits = [].

?- random_bits(Bits).
Bits = [0, 0, 0].
```

And then we can evaluate this lists of bits as a number, let's say using this approach:

```
bits_value([], 0).
bits_value([Bit | Bits], Value) :-
    bits_value(Bits, TailValue),
    Value is TailValue * 2 + Bit.
```

Examples:

```
?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [1, 1, 0],
Value = 3.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 1, 0],
Value = 2.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
Value = 24.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 1],
Value = 2.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [],
Value = 0.
```

These lists are not bounded in length, but they do tend to be short, hence the values are fairly low. We can modify the 0.25 factor in `random_length` to make longer lists more likely. For example, with 0.01:

```
?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
Value = 64.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0|...],
Value = 137345267061686159418.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0|...],
Value = 105607189397659.

?- random_bits(Bits), bits_value(Bits, Value).
Bits = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
Value = 104.
```

There are many things that could be modified in this, for example, lists containing only zeros are not very useful. You could add an "implicit 1" element to such lists. You could also treat one of the bits as a sign bit to allow generation of negative numbers. You could generate random, entirely unbounded rational numbers by generating two random integers `P` and `Q` and using `P/Q` as the random value. And so on.

Comment: This is all fine but I don't see how it addresses the real problem with the question. It is an ill-defined question, it does not explain what "infinity" is supposed to mean, what is the context, what is the use case and so on. I still maintain that a random number between 0 and infinity is infinity; if this is not true, I would like to see at least an informal proof.

Comment: The point is, whatever you do with lists and bits, you are just generating a "random" number in a finite range, maybe skewed somehow.

Comment: If I roll a 6-sided die, the largest number I can get is 6; there is a fixed upper bound. If I roll my program, the largest number I can get is not bounded. Name any number; if its list representation fits into memory, my program will essentially generate that number, and numbers larger than it as well. I don't understand why you say that my program's numbers are within a finite range. (Memory isn't even a limit on the range as such: If we exceed memory, the program will generate *nothing*, rather than something that fits into memory.)

Comment: Also note that my answer doesn't mention "infinity" at all, so your notion that "a random number between 0 and infinity is infinity", strange as it is, has nothing to do with it. My program doesn't generate "a random number between 0 and infinity" if you don't want it to. It generates (skewed) random integers >= 0 and without an upper bound. Maybe this helps you sort out your philosophical objections.